# How is this substitution happening for non-homogeneous DE?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, homogeneous-equation

I'm currently learning about homogeneous differential equations, and my material has this example

$$(x+y-2)dx + (x-y+4)dy = 0$$

This is not homogeneous, so to make it, we solve for the system of
$$x + y = 2$$
$$x - y = -4$$
And get $x = -1$ and $y = 3$

Then we substitute, let
$$x = \bar x - 1$$
$$y = \bar y + 3$$

Now, the original equation becomes 
$$(\bar x - 1 + (\bar y + 3 ) - 2)d(\bar x - 1) + (\bar x - 1 - (\bar y + 3) + 4)d(\bar y + 3) = 0$$

Simplifying the constants out, I get
$$(\bar x + \bar y)d(\bar x - 1) + (\bar x - \bar y)d(\bar y + 3)$$

While the material I have goes straight from the unsimplified expression straight to
$$(\bar x + \bar y)d\bar x + (\bar x - \bar y)d\bar y$$

And then solves the DE from there. 
I honestly am very confused with the substitutions for x and y where the differentials also gain the constants, but then in the final expression the constants are gone. My material goes straight from the unsimplified expression to the simplified one with $d\bar x$ instead of the one I got $d(\bar x - 1)$

Where is this simplification coming from? I can't continue learning the material until I understand why this happens, but I can't figure it out.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you asking `Why do we use this method to make a non-homo. to a homo. ODE?`

Comment: @BabakS. Sorry, I accidentally left an old misleading title, but I fixed it. I'm asking how the final expression my professor gets is (xbar + ybar)d(xbar) ... as opposed to (xbar + ybar)d(xbar - 1) ... . I can't figure out how the -1 is getting removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that the derivative of a constant is zero. Hence
$$d(\bar x - 1)=d(\bar x) - d(1)=d\bar x.$$

Comment: Thank you! I was confused a bit because I haven't seen the differential operator with multiple terms enclosed, next to another term before.